# TPL Dataflow Blocks

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, tpl-dataflow

Question: Why using a `WriteOnceBlock` (or `BufferBlock`) for getting back the answer (like sort of callback) from another `BufferBlock<Action>` (getting back the answer happens in that posted `Action`) causes a deadlock (in this code)?

I thought that methods in a class can be considered as messages that we are sending to the object (like the original point of view about OOP that was proposed by - I think - Alan Kay). So I wrote this generic `Actor` class that helps to convert and ordinary object to an `Actor` (Of-course there are lots of unseen loopholes here because of mutability and things, but that's not the main concern here).

So we have these definitions:

```
public class Actor<T>
{
    private readonly T _processor;
    private readonly BufferBlock<Action<T>> _messageBox = new BufferBlock<Action<T>>();

    public Actor(T processor)
    {
        _processor = processor;
        Run();
    }

    public event Action<T> Send
    {
        add { _messageBox.Post(value); }
        remove { }
    }

    private async void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var action = await _messageBox.ReceiveAsync();
            action(_processor);
        }
    }
}

public interface IIdGenerator
{
    long Next();
}
```

Now; why this code works:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var idGenerator1 = new IdInt64();

    var idServer1 = new Actor<IIdGenerator>(idGenerator1);

    const int n = 1000;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var t = new Task(() =>
        {
            var answer = new WriteOnceBlock<long>(null);

            Action<IIdGenerator> action = x =>
            {
                var buffer = x.Next();

                answer.Post(buffer);
            };

            idServer1.Send += action;

            Trace.WriteLine(answer.Receive());
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning); // Runs on a separate new thread
        t.Start();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("press any key you like! :)");
    Console.ReadKey();

    Trace.Flush();
}
```

And this code does not work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var idGenerator1 = new IdInt64();

    var idServer1 = new Actor<IIdGenerator>(idGenerator1);

    const int n = 1000;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var t = new Task(() =>
        {
            var answer = new WriteOnceBlock<long>(null);

            Action<IIdGenerator> action = x =>
            {
                var buffer = x.Next();

                answer.Post(buffer);
            };

            idServer1.Send += action;

            Trace.WriteLine(answer.Receive());
        }, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness); // Runs and is managed by Task Scheduler 
        t.Start();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("press any key you like! :)");
    Console.ReadKey();

    Trace.Flush();
}
```

Different `TaskCreationOptions` used here to create `Task`s. Maybe I am wrong about TPL Dataflow concepts here, just started to use it (A `[ThreadStatic]` hidden somewhere?).

Comment: Where do you get blocked? What's behind WaitForExit?

Comment: I replaced `WaitForExit` with it's body; it's basically just a call to `Console.ReadKey()`.

Comment: I expect that `Run()` from `Actor` class, executes `Action`s posted to `_messageBox`, one by one asynchronously; right? The thing that I do not understand is why in second code (in which `Task`s are created using `TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness` option); `Run()` does not process the values in `_messageBox` (which is a `BufferBlock`)?

Comment: I must add that there are many problems with this code. Using `async void`, event subscription instead of method call, `new Task` instead of `Task.Run` and I don't get why are you using `WriteOnceBlock`

Comment: `WriteOnceBlock` is used just as an await-able-answer container; so there would be no need for some `ManualResetEvent` and things. Your points about code are valid. But the problem here is not caused by them; and I do not know why this happens.

Comment: Considering you only have 1 thread that executes the actions, and each task has it's own variable you don't need to be thread safe. you can just have a variable (`long`) defined where the `WriteOnceBlock` is defined now. The problem is blocking on `answer.Receive()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problematic issue with your code is this part: `answer.Receive()`.
When you move it inside the action the deadlock doesn't happen:

```
var t = new Task(() =>
{
    var answer = new WriteOnceBlock<long>(null);
    Action<IIdGenerator> action = x =>
    {
        var buffer = x.Next();
        answer.Post(buffer);
        Trace.WriteLine(answer.Receive());
    };
    idServer1.Send += action;
});
t.Start();
```

So why is that? `answer.Receive();`, as opposed to `await answer.ReceiveAsnyc();` blocks the thread until an answer is returned. When you use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` each task gets its own thread, so there's no problem, but without it (the `TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness` is irrelevant) all the thread pool threads are busy waiting and so everything is much slower. It doesn't actually deadlock, as you can see when you use 15 instead of 1000.

There are other solutions that help understand the problem:

- Increasing the thread pool with `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 0);` before the original code.
- Using `ReceiveAsnyc`:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var answer = new WriteOnceBlock<long>(null);
    Action<IIdGenerator> action = x =>
    {
        var buffer = x.Next();
        answer.Post(buffer);
    };
    idServer1.Send += action;          
    Trace.WriteLine(await answer.ReceiveAsync());
});
```

Comment: Just a side note: `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 0);` won't do what you expect. First `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(1000, 0);` needs to be called and then `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 0);` would take effect.

Comment: Thanks for then answer; BTW is there a pattern for implementing awaitable-answer-container?

Comment: @KavehShahbazian not that I know of, but you can still use `WriteOnceBlock` just make sure you're asynchronously waiting and not blocking a thread.

Comment: Thanks, yet my mistakes about "Asynchronous" and "Parallel" reminds me of my mistakes about "Value Types" and "Reference Types" of my old days. This one needs more awareness. :)